# list files inside SFTP with Python to download files listdir

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I have to download some files from sftp using Python, I've tried to use listdir to list all of them, but my first attempt to use pysftp.listdir I receive this message :
"module 'pysftp' has no attribute 'listdir'

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

myHostname = "99.99.999.999"
myUsername = "user"
myPassword = "*********"

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword,cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
    pysftp.cd('public')
    pysftp.listdir()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
pysftp.cd('public')
pysftp.listdir()
```

To:

```
sftp.cd('public')
sftp.listdir()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `with` keyword and then `as sftp`, that means you should use `sftp.lisdir()`.